# Is it possible for webservice to read apiservice via container_name on docker?e.g. http://container_name:port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and I composed a web service and other services used in the web in a docker-compose file. I wonder if it's possible to have access to the services(e.g. api service) for the web service via container_name.
like http://container_name:8080. Container_name is specified in docker-compose file, and web service on docker containers can read other service via http://localhost:port. I want to replace localhost to container_name, can docker do this mapping via some configuration? I tried depends_on and links and none of them work.

Part of my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
 mywebservice:
   container_name: mywebservice
   ports:
    - "8080:80"
   depends_on:
    - myapiservice
 myapiservice:
   container_name:myapiservice
   ports:
     - "8081:80"
```

Comment: This should work fine; you can delete `container_name:` and it will still work.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details.  Are you trying to make a call from inside `mywebservice` to `myapiservice` and produce a rendered page; or is `mywebservice` serving a browser-based application that makes a fetch call from outside Docker space?

Comment: Yeah actually I’m trying to call from inside mywebservice to myapiservice.I want to use some name configured in docker file to replace the localhost in my url

Comment: `mywebservice` should be able to reliably call `http://myapiservice` (on the default HTTP port 80).  If this doesn't work, can you provide the code that's making the call, and the actual error you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve your container name to the container ip via the hosts file.

```
192.168.10.10   mywebservice
```

You can have this file in your application source and get docker to copy it to `/etc`

Comment: Thanks! This solved the question but here’s anothter question- this just built a name -  address mapping and they have nothing todo with docker compose files’s container_name. They are not the same thing:o Everytime I change the container_name I have to change that in host files too,and if I use another pc to pull images and composeup,I also have to set the host again

Comment: Use the `command` option in the docker-compose and create the `hosts` file from within your docker compose script. This way you can have the name only in one place.

Comment: The container IP isn't accessible except in one very specific Docker/host setup, and I wouldn't recommend looking it up.

Comment: Right...that can solve the problem but not recommended,thx